# Convert decimal (SQL) to double C++

Tags: c++, sql, double, decimal

I have a SQL query which return records with only one column of type decimal (18,18).

In the C++ code I need to convert each value to double to add it to an array.

What's the best way of doing it?

Thank you

Comment: What SQL library are you using?

Comment: Do you want to convert a string (witch represent a number) to a double ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest converting it to a Real before taking it from the database they are roughly the same datatype. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx