# convert from sql type decimal(20,8) to c++ double

Tags: c++, double, decimal, mysql-connector

How do i convert from sql decimal type to double WITHOUT casting the underlying database with a query as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746010/convert-decimal-sql-to-double-c) suggests. I am on MySQL and casting from decimal(20,8) to real causes errors. I am using mysql-connector c++ and it loads and runs queires fine but i cannot conver the data from the mysql-connector format to that of c++.

I am using mysql 5.1.63 hosted on linux,  while running code c++ from a different linux machine as well as well

Comment: Er, I can't see any answer saying something about changing your database.

Comment: maybe i'm mistaken , then how else would i "convert the data to real before taking it from the database"?

Comment: `REAL` is a datatype, synonymous to `DOUBLE` in MySQL if I remember correctly. I think he merely suggests that you cast it on the database side before returning it to the application.

Comment: so i could convert it via a query? googling this now

Comment: `SELECT CAST(* AS REAL) FROM`data` `     didn't work for me

Comment: yeah thats not working either so value1 would be the column1 name i presume or something else?

Comment: `"SELECT CAST(col1_name AS REAL) FROM` `dataset`   isn't working for me

Comment: Uwrgh, MySQL apparently has restrictions on types you can CAST to, DOUBLE/REAL isn't one of them.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that's a bummer i knew i wasn't crazy

Comment: well, in our codebase, we use a binding mechanism between the C++ and DB. Specifically, we use OTL to provide an easy-to-use interface that should take care of any datatype issues you're facing. Note: we still have problems with `long long`. I'm no DB expert, so does that answer your question or get you on the right track?

Comment: @AK4749 i'm using `mysql-connector` i will try out `OTL`

Comment: @pyCthon ah, I see, so I suspect it has the same type of functionality as OTL. In that case, is the MySQL Connector documentation unable to provide the proper storage type for `decimal`? OTL works by overloading << or >> for most datatype conversions. Beware of over/underflow however!!

Comment: @AK4749 in the examples on the web from their website they keep everything in the sql format, i don't want that, unless i missed something i coudln't find anything else

Comment: @pyCthon are you sure? Our code looks something like "select *field* from *table* where *condition*", open stream connection on that statement, then `stream >> var;` where var is defined as an `unsigned int` (can be whatever you want, as long as *field* was uploaded with the same data type)

Comment: except `long long`. maybe there's a way to fix that too but I haven't found it yet

Comment: MySQL Connector/C++ seems to try to emulate the JDBC API from Java. Java doesn't have stream operators like C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience using the standard C++ driver for MySQL (MySQL Connector/C++). However, I have used the MySQL++ driver.

The documentation for the MySQL Connector/C++ is pretty lacking. However, it seems to look as if it tries to stick to the JDBC API.

You can view the [documentation for JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) on the Oracle site.

I'm guessing to convert the value to double is fairly simple:

```
sql::Connection* con;

//connection code, etc.

sql::Statement* stmt = con->createStatement();
sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT big_dec FROM test");

vector<double> results;

while (res->next()) 
{
    //Allow the driver to convert it to double for you.
    double res_double = res->getDouble("big_dec");
    // You can use either numeric offsets...
    cout << "num: " << res_double << endl;

    results.push_back(res_double);
}
```

Edit:

Now you say the `double` is being converted properly, but it isn't being inserted into your `vector<double>` properly.

Try the following DIRECTLY after your loop:

```
for (vector<double>::iterator it = results.begin(); it != results.end(); it++)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Edit:

The `for` loop prints everything successfully. So we know the doubles are being added to the `vector<double>` correctly.

It sounds like you are trying to copy your `vector<double>` somewhere, but aren't doing it properly.

Are you returning this from a function?

Edit:

Problem is now solved. The `vector` issue was elsewhere.

Comment: , the problem here is that i can cout<<res_double that works fine but when i try to do a vector.push_back(res_double) or vector.push_back(res->getDouble)things go wrong,  , heres some example code http://pastebin.com/BgBDNYaC

Comment: Your result says that `cout << res_double` works fine. It sounds like your vector is having the problems, not the SQL code.

Comment: same problem when i used C-style arrays, but the result is all `6.95326e-310` instead of the desired result

Comment: Try using that for loop immediately after your while loop.

Comment: the vector was declared imediatly before the while loop as in the example,

Comment: That's not what I asked. You said the `vector` didn't print the values correctly at first. Where were you accessing the `vector` when that happened? Was it after returning it from a function? Does it still fail to print the values there?

Comment: i had a serous "PEBKAC" error , the double conversion was the only problem

Comment: Hahahaha, awesome! Glad that I could help then. The documentation for MySQL Connector/C++ kinda sucks, but looking at the JDBC documentation for Java might be a little useful if you run into more problems.

Comment: To rule out vector issues in your example, try `cout<<res->getDouble(4)` if this prints the expected value, then connector done the conversion ok and the problem lies elsewhere in your code. Assuming of course the 4th column in your resultrow is indeed of numeric/decimal type.